# Which Schema should I use on a website that displays soccer's results?

Tags: seo, schema.org

I was looking for a schema to include on a website that displays soccer results. I was thinking about *Article*, but I'm not sure if it's the right schema. Could someone tell me if there is any other schema that fits better? Or should I go with Article? Thanks!

Comment: There is no point to using a schema without knowing what rich snippet you want first.  You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I just want to let know Google that I have results of different soccer matches and want to show that results on Google.

Comment: Google only uses schema for changing how the results look in certain cases. Things like reviews and recipes.   While Google sometimes does have a special display for sports scores, I don't believe it is powered by schema.  Most does don't need to use any schema.